# CSS - Box Shadow - what is 0+0+0+0+2in#color

Tags: html, css

Long Story Short:

Youtube Video => CSS Battles => Me Visiting https://cssbattle.dev/play/1 => Found It Interesting => Solved Challenge No. 1(Super Easy) => Googled Best answer after looking at the results => My thoughts after looking at the best =>[solution](https://dev.to/pheeria/css-battle-1-simply-square-c19) <= {"Am I seriously a coder","Is that really CSS","Do Black holes Exist?"}, But jokes Apart, the Best Solution which is mentioned below made me feel like why am I not aware of such a thing?

The Website cssbattles displays an image and asks the challenger to replicate the exact same thing with html and css with exact precision. The Solution with the least characters wins(Winner claims all the glory).

Challenge
[image]

The Solution

`<img style=box-shadow:0+0+0+2in#b5e0ba,0+0+0+5in#5d3a3a>`

(I simply Have No Idea What The Above Mentioned Line Means)

found this answer at https://dev.to/pheeria/css-battle-1-simply-square-c19

Maybe I'm noob in CSS, but I tried searching for it on the internet but could not find the answer I needed.

I thought maybe this is just some short hand property for things I found [here at MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) or [here at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/). But I could not get what I was looking for despite trying to change and test the values .

Please Note: Answer to such a question may exist and may have multiple instances of same thing already available on stack overflow itself, so kindly ignore my inability to search for answers and help me with answers or Links to existing Solutions.

Can someone please explain what is that code?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: [RTM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

Comment: What's the great mystery? `box-shadow` can contain multiple comma-separated values. The spacing  and plusses in the answer just make it harder to read. An equivalent is `0 0 0 2in #b5e0ba, 0 0 0 5in #5d3a3a` where `in` is the unit of inches.

Comment: Somehow i could not get the same result when I tried separating the values with space instead of '+'

Comment: Must be because it's inline instead of in a separate stylesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER:** The pluses are ugly and seem to be a way to save the quotes in the attribute to make the shortest code possible as an inline attribute - Not recommended since it may not work in all browsers.

Details about the code

[MDN Box shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

> Box-shadow property adds shadow effects around an element's frame. You can set multiple effects separated by commas. A box shadow is described by X and Y offsets relative to the element, blur and spread radius, and color.

[CSS-Tricks box shadow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/)

> box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];

```css
span {
box-shadow: 0+0+0+2in #b5e0ba, /* 2" green spread */
            0+0+0+5in #5d3a3a  /* 5" brown spread */  
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
```

In chrome Same as

```css
span {
box-shadow: 0 0 0 2in #b5e0ba, /* 2" green spread */
            0 0 0 5in #5d3a3a  /* 5" brown spread */  
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
```

Comment: I know what box-shadow does, I need to know what those parameters mean. They aren't the same as what one would get when typing (box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #ccc)

Comment: I see no difference to `box-shadow: 0 0 0 2in #b5e0ba, 0 0 0 5in #5d3a3a `

Comment: Either you did not even care to try out your own answer or my browser is lying to me, but I don't get the same same result when trying your answer

Comment: In chrome. And yes I did. Thanks for the trust

Comment: The 0+0 is ugly and I bet they did this to save the quotes in the style attr